# Use jQuery to get value from this JSON string

Tags: jquery, json

Seems like this should be easy!

I am submitting a form via jQuery/ajax and the success output is a JSON sting like this:

```
{"activities-tracker-steps":[{"dateTime":"2016-09-06","value":"0"}]}
```

All I want to do is get the value (in this case 0). So, I try this:

```
        submitHandler: function() {
        var postData = $("#form").serializeArray();
        var formURL = $("#form").attr("action");
        $.ajax({
            url : formURL,
            type: "POST",
            data : postData,
            success : function(data) {
                var json;
                json = $.parseJSON(data);
                alert(json['value']);
                $('#form').trigger("reset");            
                $("#success").show().fadeOut(3000);
            },
            error : function() {
                $("#fail").show().fadeOut(3000);
            }
        });
    }
```

Undefined, apparently. What am I doing wrong!?

Many thanks for your thoughts,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per provided structure you can fetch value by `json['activities-tracker-steps'][0].value` as mentioned below.

```
submitHandler: function() {
        var postData = $("#form").serializeArray();
        var formURL = $("#form").attr("action");
        $.ajax({
            url : formURL,
            type: "POST",
            data : postData,
            success : function(data) {
                var json;
                json = $.parseJSON(data);
                alert(json['activities-tracker-steps'][0].value);
                $('#form').trigger("reset");            
                $("#success").show().fadeOut(3000);
            },
            error : function() {
                $("#fail").show().fadeOut(3000);
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Brilliant, thanks! Does [0] represent the first layer of an array then?

Comment: value is property of that object which is in array, you can console.log(json) after parse json. and check in inspect view of browser....

If you like and work then dont forget to mark as correct and upvote it.